# Layout of ListView is overlapping

Tags: android, listview, overlap

Just now the layout in my Listview has gotten slightly messed up: The textviews in every row are now wrapped while they should be free to fill the screen horizontally.

EDIT: updated text to more accurately describe the current situation.
EDIT2: This is want the UI is supposed to look like:

[image]

The above part is what it's supposed to look like and the below part is what is currently displaying.

My ListView layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/goal_name"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/goal_progress"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seperator"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/seperator"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/goal_limit"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <!-- 
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
     -->

  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My main page layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="nl.tizin.healthapp.GoalMainScreen$PlaceholderFragment">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/name_header_text"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/day_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/day_header_text"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_of_goals"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">     
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_goal_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_goals_added"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_exercise_goal_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_exercise_goal_button_text"
        android:onClick="addExerciseGoal"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_food_goal_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_food_goal_button_text"
        android:onClick="addFoodGoal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.goal_main_screen);
    mGoalList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_of_goals);
    mGoalList.setEmptyView((View) findViewById(R.id.empty_goal_list));
    mGoalList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Cursor c = (Cursor) mGoalList.getItemAtPosition(position);
            //Get ID of goal and increment day value
            checkInGoal(c.getInt(0));
            System.out.println(c.getString(1));
        }
    });
    populateList();
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could help as I've been staring at this for way too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters your listview layout does not close the `RelativeLayout` tag.

You might want to add the attribute:

`android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/goal_name`"

in your `LinearLayout`

Might I suggest weighting your views:

add attribute:

```
android:layout_weight="<some percentage>"
```

in each `child view` (ie: .8)

and attribute:

```
android:weightSum="1"
```

to the `parent view`

**EDIT**

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:weightSum="1"
        >

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/goal_name_header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:text="Goal Name Header"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/goal_progress_header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Progress Header"

            />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:weightSum="1"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/goal_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Goal Name "

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/goal_progress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Progress "

            />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, that's caused by me not pasting the code correctly. I'll edit the port right away.

Comment: Your suggestion has helped in that the textviews are no longer overlapping but they're still clumped together. The android:layout_centerHorizontal tag seems to be getting ignored.

Comment: I should clarify that currently the only issue is that the content inside the listview seem to be wrapped while they should be free to fill the screen as dictated by the android:layout_centerHorizontal and android:layout_alignParentLeft tags.

Comment: @JHeikes try some padding attributes to get the desired spacing.

Comment: @JHeikes Plz provide a sample of how you want it to look.

Comment: I'd like it to look just like the two textviews in my main layout. The first textview is aligned with the left side of the screen and the second is centered in the screen. The list items are supposed to be aligned the same way but they're wrapped for some reason, resulting in them being aligned on the left side of the screen (they also overlapped at first, before I added your first suggestion).

Comment: @JHeikes I think you want to change the `LinearLayout` orientation to `vertical` and change toRightOf to `layout_below`.  Without an example drawing depicting exactly what you want, it's difficult to see.

Comment: I have updated the main post with a link to a quick sketch of how it is supposed to look.

Comment: @JHeikes Plz see my edit.  I think this is what you are looking for based on what I saw in the link example.  `The text is there for reference only`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you changed from LinearLayout to RelativeLayout. Close the RelativeLayout tag and remove the orientation attribute.

Comment: The RelativeLayout is closed properly but the code wasn't formatted properly so it didn't show in the post.

Comment: What about removing the orientation attributes in your RelativeLayouts?

Comment: Removing the orientation attributes doesn't do anything either.